# Divs not moving down within parent section

Tags: html, css

Here is the website with the current code: http://www.actuatecontent.com

I am building my first website and I am trying to move down two Divs within a container div and they simply won't budge down. (`.copy` and `.btn_section` )

What am I doing wrong, and how can I correct it?

Thanks for your help!

Source code:

```css
.second_section .container {
 position: relative;
 top: 300px;
 background-image: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-I0jOcWYqW94/UdFZ9U8Si0I/AAAAAAAACRw/2Hhb0xY7yzY/s1600/84.jpg);
 height: 900px;
 width: 100%;
}

.copy {
 top: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 2px

}

.btn_section {
 position: relative;
 top: 300px;
 text-align: center;
}

.btn {

 margin-top: 100px
 color: white;
 border: solid 2px fixed;
}

.btn_section a {
 border: 1px solid white;
 padding: 20px 40px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #191919;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.33em;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="AC_css.css"/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600'    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">

 <div class="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="second_section">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="copy">
  <h1>ACTUATE CONTENT</h1>
   <br>
   <h3>Expert Content For Every Business</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="btn_section">
   <a href="#" class="btn">Write For Me!</a>

  </div>
 </div>

<div class="third_section">
 </div>

<div class="fourth_section">
 

 <div class="col">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-smart-pack/128/grey_new_seo2-17-256.png"><h2>RESEARCH</h2></a>
  
  <br>
  <p>Our meticulous research methods will uncover the most relevant information for your project. </p>
 </div>

 <div class="col">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/55-files-and-documents/512/Icon_17-512.png">
  <h2>WRITING</h2></a>
  <br>
  <p>Our seasoned, handpicked writers craft stellar content for your specific needs.</p>

 </div>

 <div class="col">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/AinCaug.png">
  <h2>EDITING</h2></a>
  <br>
  <p>Our editors work with leading authors and publishers to bring out the best in their writing.</p>
 </div>
 
</div>

<div class="footer">
 <div class="footer_info">
  <a href="#"><p>Designed by Ashwin Reddy / &copy; Ashwin Reddy</p></a>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: HERE IS THE WEBPAGE: http://actuatecontent.com/

Answer (score 0):

try adding a padding-top into your .container class. for eg:

```css
.second_section .container {
padding-top:200px;
        background-image: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-I0jOcWYqW94/UdFZ9U8Si0I/AAAAAAAACRw/2Hhb0xY7yzY/s1600/84.jpg);
        height: 900px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... I added but nothing changed.

Comment: shouldn't be. your Actuate content section and the "write  for me" button should move down. double check if your html tag has misplaced? maybe missing a closing tag or nested into other tag?

Comment: Also I see something wrong in my chrome dev tools, under .btn, .btn_section and .container sections, I see a position: relative rule set, but I don't have that in my code in sublime now, I thought I removed it but it doesn't update? I have the index.html and CSS file on my computer... this is the link I used in the HTML file: <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ac_css.css"/>

Comment: OK... never mind the above ... it does show in my code.  Clearly I need some coffee.